# Multiple outputs per input in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to get the semantics of an unbounded arc in Tensorflow without directly enqueuing in the op itself?

For example, if I want to write an operation on that takes a scalar string `my_string` and "emits" tuples of `("string", num_occurrences_in_my_string)`, I have to resort to either of the following output options (as far as I know):

- return the values necessary to construct a sparse Tensor
- take a queue reference (of the correct type) and directly enqueue the input myself (like [the `tf.TextLineReader` does](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TextLineReader))

As far as I can tell from [the paper from Google on the Tensorflow "programming language"](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3088527), these are the only ways to accomplish it.

*Is there a way in Tensorflow to emit an arbitrary number of output "rounds" per a given input* besides the aforementioned workarounds?